# How to set up an ActionBar Sherlock Tab?

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I'm switching my App's Tab (API 7) to the one's used in the Action Bar Sherlock because of the design, but I don't know how to set this up.

That's how I used to do:

```
    tabH = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

    tabH.setup();

    TabSpec espec = tabH.newTabSpec("tabONE");
    espec.setContent(R.id.tbhot);
    espec.setIndicator("A");
    tabH.addTab(espec);

    espec = tabH.newTabSpec("tabTWO");
    espec.setContent(R.id.tbrecente);
    espec.setIndicator("B");
    tabH.addTab(espec);

    espec = tabH.newTabSpec("tabTHREE");
    espec.setContent(R.id.tbcreate);
    espec.setIndicator("C");
    tabH.addTab(espec);
```

And now that's what I'm doing:

```
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        if (i == 1)
            tab.setText("A");
        else if(i == 2)
            tab.setText("B");
        else if (i == 3)
            tab.setText("C");
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
    }
```

That works, but I don't know how to set the Content, so all tabs have the same thing in it. How do I do it?

Also, my other tab was at the bottom of the layout. Is it possible to set this one at the bottom too? I believe that if I could set the TabHost in the new tab, it will be in the bottom too, so the question is, how to set the tabhost here?

Answer (score 0):

I typically use fragments for the content. You have to implement the ActionBar.TabListener and adjust your content there, but it's pretty easy. You can add all your fragments at the beginning and show/hide them, or replace the current fragment.

Comment: I've read about it, but isn't it avaible only for 3.0 or higher? Or will it work fine with ABS?

Comment: ABS overrides all that stuff. that's the whole point of the library. here's one of the demos from jake: [FragmentTabs](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabs.java)